# ORBEON: Is it possible to add custom headers or send a session cookie to API authoriser

Tags: javascript, authentication, orbeon

I am trying to authenticate requests in orbeon using my authoriser backend, and i need to pass a token which is available in localStorage, or pass the JSESSIONID to the API authoriser but i am not sure how to add the headers to the requests, I am thinking of intercepting the requests and inject the tokens but that is not possible considering that i cant change/add to the code.

Is there a way to forward the JSESSIONID cookie to the API authoriser, currently its not being forwarded there, or a way to pass in a custom header that is stored in localstorage.

FYI, the orbeon is running inside an Iframe and the localStorage being referred to here is the one in the iframe where orbeon is running.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, the cookies are filtered out in order to avoid other issues, however other headers are passed. If you have the option to use a custom header then things should work!